# autohotkey type in another window with gui

Tags: autohotkey

Autohotkey Example Needed

Need some help, please.  I've searched and can't seem to find an example of what I need.

What I want to do is create a ahk dialog box with a button (I can do this part), and when I click on it, it will type some text into another window.  Basically, I want want to offload the "shortcut" to a "mouse click".  But, without mapping a shortcut.

Something like this:

When user clicks BOX1, "text" is stored. Then, when user clicks elsewhere, vBOX1 is typed into the cursor location of the window activated by that click

I hope I'm explaining this succinctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You still need a hotkey. But you can use `~LButton::`, where `~` let's the hotkey be activated without blocking LButton click.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible alternatives:

**First alternative** expands @scso's suggestion:

```
~LButton::
sleep, 200 ;give the window below the cursor some time to get activated
Send, %vBOX1%
return
```

Now this may seem fine but what it actually does is type the text EVERY time you click the mouse in ANY window. Let's put an additional check so if vBOX1 is empty it doesn't type anything.

```
~LButton::
sleep, 200 ;give the window below the cursor some time to get activated
If (vBOX1 != "")
{
  Send, %vBOX1%
  vBOX1 := ""  ; clears the contents of vBOX1
}
return
```

**Second alternative**:

You use the mouse clicks normally and the text gets typed only when you do Control + Click.
So in order to type the text you need to click once to select the window and then control+click to do the actual typing

```
~^LButton::
Send, %vBOX1%
vBOX1 := ""  ; clears the contents of vBOX1
return
```

You can expand both alternatives by adding commands for detecting the active window and then typing the text or changing the mouse click combination to something else.